Cannot run Google Picasa in 24.04 in Wine
After upgrading to 24.04 I cannot run Google Picasa installed in my default wineprefix. It seems like a problem with loading the DLLs:
0024:err:module:import_dll Library coml2.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\ole32.dll") not found
0024:err:module:import_dll Library ole32.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\oleaut32.dll") not found
0024:err:module:import_dll Library oleaut32.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\urlmon.dll") not found
...

(and many others)
Is there anything I could try to fix this?

Many apps do not work with Wine. There is nothing we can do about it. Use a Windows VM. Alternatively, create a post in the Wine forum.

I didn't find the root cause of the problem so I simply created a new Wine prefix and installed fresh Picasa in it.
